# SMALLEST YOCTO IMAGE DISTRO FEATURES

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to build a small linux image using the Yocto project.While i was searching the net, i found that i can remove some DISTRO FEATURES that i don't need for my image. How can i check which distro features i m using now ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command:

`bitbake -e | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=`

To shrink Yocto image, you can base your work on `poky-tiny` and look at ***Building a tiny system*** [manual chapter](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#building-a-tiny-system).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. Besides, do you have an idea how i can remove some distro features which are shown for me and i don't need them like Bluetooth and others ? and I think that i must re-build the image after that

Comment: You could try to remove those in `local.conf` file with `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "xxx"` but best option is to select `poky-tiny` as `DISTRO` or create a custom DISTRO from it.

Comment: Okey I will check the yocto manual and i will try to build poky-tiny distro

Comment: Hello buddy, please do you know how to use musl Libc instead of Glibc to reduce the size of my rootfs ? In fact i removed Distro features that i don't need but the size was reduced by 2 Mega octet only and the big sized one is Glibc that i want to replace

Comment: You have to set [TCLIBC](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky-tiny.conf#n34) variable, it's default option with `poky-tiny`.